# Best way to run an entire script via ruby -e

Tags: ruby, shell

I've been wanting to run some ruby scripts on remote computers (in a bash shell)

I could create a sequence of bash commands of `ruby -e "<command>"`, but some of these scripts are over 100 lines.

`ruby -e` with a HEREDOC or `%{}` & `eval()` doesn't work well with the mixture of single and double quotes.

Is there a better way to attempt this?

Edit:

The protocol being used is Apple Remote Desktop, which executes these commands in the scope of the remote shell.

Comment: Hrm, do I understand you correctly that you are trying to push that to `ssh` invocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I *also* want to run ruby scripts via ARD (which I don't think can embed a ctrl-D), I first thought you *could* combine joraff's solution (to his own problem) with Kelvin's:

```
cat << ENDOFSCRIPT | ruby

#Here be code ...

ENDOFSCRIPT
```

Which saves creating/deleting a file.

### But there's an even better way:

It turns out (duh) that ARD embeds an EOF or just otherwise terminates what it sends in such a way that you can simply do:

```
ruby

#Paste whole script here
```

Works at least in ARD 3.6.1. Win!

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you want to run local ruby script on remote machine via SSH or similar protocol. If the script is non-interactive (i.e. doesn't require any user input), you could create it locally and deliver through `stdin`.

In other words, first write the script and save it locally as, say, `foo.rb`. Then:

```
ssh remotehost ruby < foo.rb
```

That with start the SSH session and execute the remote ruby interpreter. With no arguments, the ruby interpreter executes commands from standard input, and thus we feed SSH with the program on stdin.

Comment: At that point it'd work just as well to do `ssh remotehost ruby foo.rb` wouldn't it?

Comment: No. `ssh remotehost ruby foo.rb` would cause ruby to read `foo.rb` from the remote host. `<foo.rb` makes local bash read `foo.rb` from the local host.

Comment: `<foo.rb` tells the local shell to read the local file. `ssh remotehost "ruby foo.rb"` would be correct though.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. `foo.rb` is not on the remote server.

Comment: Ah. "Locally", I missed that part. Yes, you are correct about that. I always push my scripts to the remote side as part of a source distribution.

Comment: Apple Remote Desktop is the protocol being used, which executes all commands in the scope of the remote shell. `< foo.rb` would be reading from the wrong computer.

Comment: `ruby < ` also only reads one line from stdin before executing and exiting, from what I can tell.

Comment: @joraff: I have no idea what 'Apple Remote Desktop' is but probably another crippled proprietary 'standard'. Can't you feed it with data stream? Also, `ruby <` reads whole script. I've tested it before pasting.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
cat << 'EOF' > /tmp/myscript.rb

# ruby script contents go here. any syntax is valid, except for your limit string (EOF)

EOF

ruby /tmp/myscript.rb;
rm /tmp/myscript.rb;
```

Since this isn't relying on how an interpreter binary handles stdin-style commands, it will work for most other languages as well (python, perl, php).

Comment: Is this any different from just running `ruby` with no args, pasting the code (with trailing newline), and pressing ctrl-D to send EOF?

Answer (score 0):

Why not send the script over first?

```
scp foo.rb remotehost:
ssh remotehost "ruby foo.rb"
```

You could even clean up the file after:

```
ssh remotehost "rm foo.rb"
```

Comment: Because the protocol being used (Apple Remote Desktop) executes all commands in the scope of the remote shell. If anything, I'd have to scp from the outside, but this process is not interactive.

Comment: This task isn't interactive, not sure i could send a control character.